# *** caught segfault *** address 0x38, cause 'memory not mapped' when using googlesheets4::gs4_auth

Tags: r, googlesheets4

I have problem when calling `googlesheets4::gs4_auth()` using json path

> googlesheets4::gs4_auth(path = auth_jspath)

#### This is error log:

*** caught segfault *** address 0x38, cause 'memory not mapped'. Warning: stack imbalance in 'lazyLoadDBfetch', 33 then 27

An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ... Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x38, cause 'memory not mapped'
Warning: stack imbalance in 'lazyLoadDBfetch', 33 then 27


Traceback:
 1: curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)
 2: request_fetch.write_memory(req$output, req$url, handle)
 3: request_fetch(req$output, req$url, handle)
 4: request_perform(req, hu$handle$handle)
 5: httr::GET(url, httr::add_headers(`Metadata-Flavor` = "Google"))
 6: force(expr)
 7: httr::with_config(httr::timeout(timeout), {    httr::GET(url, httr::add_headers(`Metadata-Flavor` = "Google"))})
 8: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 9: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
10: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
11: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        sm <- strsplit(conditionMessage(e), "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && isTRUE(getOption("show.error.messages"))) {        cat(msg, file = outFile)        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
12: try({    httr::with_config(httr::timeout(timeout), {        httr::GET(url, httr::add_headers(`Metadata-Flavor` = "Google"))    })}, silent = TRUE)
13: gce_metadata_request("", stop_on_error = FALSE)
14: detect_gce()
15: f(scopes, ...)
16: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
17: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
18: tryCatchList(expr, names[-nh], parentenv, handlers[-nh])
19: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
20: tryCatchOne(tryCatchList(expr, names[-nh], parentenv, handlers[-nh]),     names[nh], parentenv, handlers[[nh]])
21: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
22: tryCatch(f(scopes, ...), warning = function(e) {    gargle_debug(c("Warning caught by {.fun token_fetch}:", e$message))    NULL}, error = function(e) {    gargle_debug(c("Error caught by {.fun token_fetch}:", e$message))    NULL})
23: gargle::token_fetch(scopes = scopes, app = gs4_oauth_app() %||%     gargle::tidyverse_app(), email = email, path = path, package = "googlesheets4",     cache = cache, use_oob = use_oob, token = token)
24: gs4_auth(path = auth_jspath)
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

#### My sessionInfo()

```
## R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
## 
## Matrix products: default
## BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
## LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.so
## 
## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8    LC_NUMERIC=C           
##  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8     LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 
##  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=C          
##  [7] LC_PAPER=C              LC_NAME=C              
##  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C            LC_TELEPHONE=C         
## [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=C        LC_IDENTIFICATION=C    
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] rmarkdown_1.11
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] compiler_3.5.2  magrittr_1.5    tools_3.5.2     htmltools_0.3.6
##  [5] yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.0      stringi_1.2.4   knitr_1.21     
##  [9] stringr_1.3.1   xfun_0.4        digest_0.6.18   evaluate_0.12
```

Package version:

`googlesheets4` 0.3.0
`gargle` 1.1.0

I did not know what happening. Please help check. Thank you all.

Comment: A few questions: Did the sheet you were accessing require authentication or was it 'public'? Do you allow core_dump writes, can test/find out `ulimit -c` if 0, not writing. Even with a core dump, if you didn't compile R with debug symbols, running core dump through gdb won't be useful. What, generally was the instruction you gave that resulted in the seg-fault?

Comment: Sorry about late respone. Hmm, I haven't undestand your question yet. But in "Did the sheet you were accessing require authentication or was it 'public'", It needs authenize. The json file will help me authenize, i do not need to accept them in browser. And I use 2 other environments. In local Rtudio, yes, it works well, but when I use in R server session (not in local), one environment worked and another didn't, instead of both of them have sample version package. @Chris

Comment: It seems accepted that if you can provoke a seg fault, even if `it's something you did`, it merits reporting to maintainers as strengthening code can't necessarily anticipate `all the things we might do`, until it is done.